# How to use fetch when I am not interested in the returned value?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I usually use `fetch` like this:

```
fetch(`http://some.api.com`)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => someFunctionThatUsesR(r))
```

I recently had a case when I needed to call an API where

- was not interested in the result
- I needed to call another function upon fulfillment

```
fetch(`http://some.api.com`)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(r => someFunction())
```

This works but my IDE warned me about the fact that `r` is not used.

This led me to the question: **is there a better/more <del>JSonic</del> JavaScriptic way to handle that?** (= so that there is no need to drag the results between the `then()`s)

Comment: wouldn't using `someFunction(r)` get rid of that warning? What does "JSonic" mean?

Comment: just use `.then(() => someFunction())` (which is the same as `.then(someFunction)`, assuming `someFunction` doesn't reference `this`)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think he means JavaScriptic, a la Pythonic.

Comment: `.json()` [isn't unnecessary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). it converts a response stream into body text as json

Comment: @evolutionxbox, as Barman said - I copied "Pythonic", I will change it to the proper expression

Comment: @WoJ thanks, it did confuse my little brain

Comment: @Barmar: yes, I indeed meant that. I edited the question with the correct lingo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using the result, you don't need the `r` parameter. You also don't need to call `r.text()`.

```
fetch(`http://some.api.com`)
    .then(() => someFunction());
```

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. My automated way of using `fetch` left me with the impression I need to chain two `then()` to be in the state "the call is done) but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise jhas a great diagram which explains your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```cs
fetch(`http://some.api.com`)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(someFunction)
```